# React Native - Search for Value, Choosing from dropdwon List and Entering a new value that is not on the list

Tags: typescript, react-native, search, textinput

Problem: I want the user to be able to enter a new value in text input, not only selecting one from the dropdown list.

For the moment the user cannot do that. What should I fix so the user can do both?

Example: The user enters the term Test, the options from the dropdown are "Test1", "Test2", but he wants to enter the value of "Test 3". With my implementation the user is  only allowed to choose from list of dropdown

```
        const [showValueDropdown,setShowValueDropdown ] = useState<boolean>(false);
        const [selectedValue, setSelectedValue] = useState('');
    
    
        //Function to select from the dropdown items 
    
         const handleSelectedValues = (value: IValue): void => {
                setShowValueDropdown(false);
                const valueData= `${value.name} (${value.secondName})`;
                  setSelectedValue(valueData);
               
              };
    //Function to show dropdown items with dispatch
              const selectValue= async (term: string): Promise<void> => {
                const code= await LocalStorage.get(CODE); // code from backend to dispatch the request so the desired list of values can come.
                  dispatch(valueData({ CODE, term }));
                  setShowValueDropdown(term.length > 0);
                
              };
            
          
              return (
                <View>
                  <View>
                    <View>            
               <TextInput
                    editable={true}                      //Text input to enter the term
                    placeholder={placeholder}
                    returnKeyType='done'
                    autoCorrect={false}
                    defaultValue={selectedValue}
                    onChangeText={text => selectValue(text)}
                  />
                </View>
              </View>
    
            
                  {listofValues.length > 0 && showValuesDropdown  && (  //Rendering selected values from text input
    
                    <View>
                      {listOfValues.map((value, ind) => (
                        <View>
                          <Text
                            onPress={() => {
                              handelSelectedValues(value);
                            }}
                          >
                            {value.name} ({value.nameSecond})
                          </Text>
                        </View>
                      ))}
                    </View>
                  )}
                </View>
```

Comment: It is unclear to me what you are trying to achieve. Should the input of `TextInput` be added to `listOfValues` if not present?

Comment: listOfValues is only the prefilled list coming from backend, displayed to the user when he starts typing. The value that is not present on the list can also be passed as a new value but not related to the list. For the moment user can only choose from the options that appear from the dropdown, not being able to add a input that is not related to the listOfValues. Maybe you can think of this  like a search: when you search for a term you can choose an option that is search before or make a new search term. Hope it is clear to you now